# For loop or fast enumeration of nsarray with a skip or step

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, enumeration

I have an NSArray and I need to perform an action every two items on those two items. So I assume it is like a step value or something like it.

Start the loop, run my command on the first two items and then loop and run my command on the next two items - until the array is exhausted.

Any ideas on how to do this? I thought using a modulus but that can help with even odd, right? I need even and odd every 2.

My code that is hardwired to run on the first two items is below. I would like to add many more items and have the loop intelligently skip every two after the action and start the loop over again.

```
for (int i = 0; i  < 2; i ++) {
    shut01Path  = CGPathCreateMutable();
    shut01Path = CGPathCreateMutableCopy([self buildPathAtIndex:i].CGPath);
    [arr_cgPathArray addObject:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:shut01Path]];
}
```

Comment: By the way, example code is quite messy. If your `buildPathAtIndex:` return `UIBeziezPath`, then just `copy` it and add to the array.

Answer (score 1):

Simply increment the counter **by two**:

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i  < array.count; i += 2) {
    id even = array[i];
    id odd = array[i + 1]; // Make sure the array has even count, otherwise this crashes.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check the index value at the beginning of each iteration of your for-loop. 
If your index value starts at zero and is incremented by 1 then you can check using modulo 
If the index % 2 is zero, you've got an even number. Otherwise odd number. 
Other conditions and indexing schemes may require fancier math or enable other conditional checks.

This is really standard C and general programming.

Comment: Might be standard, but I was having trouble which is why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

This code steps for me. Change s as needed.

```
int s = [array count]/4;
for (int i = 0; i  < s; i ++) {
    NSLog(@"%i",(i*s));
    NSLog(@"%i",(i*s) + 1);
}
```